# Prove/disprove given statement(s) is/are true/false

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Let $\Theta(x, y, z)$ be the statement $“x+y=z”$ and let there be two quantifications given as:

$(i). \forall x \forall y \exists z, \Theta(x, y, z)$

$(ii).  \exists Z \forall x \forall y, \Theta(x, y, z)$

where $x, y, z$ are real numbers. Then which one of the following is/are TRUE ?

---

My attempt:

Well, known statement $(i)$ is true, and $(ii)$ is false.(I agreed).

And somewhere, it explained as : $x+y=z$  for all $x$ for all $y$ there exist some $z$ which will satisfy this equation as e.g $x=4351$ $y=1111$ then some $z =5462$ is there and so on.

for some $z$ say $z=100$ there do not exist all $x$ and all $y$ (there exist only some $x, y$ ) which satisfies this equation hence $(ii)$ is false.

OK, my question is: but how we prove in mathematical way?

> Can you explain it, please?

Comment: (Since it is tagged number theory) Standard $+$ is closed in $\mathbb{Z}$, so $x +y$ must result in another integer $n$. Set $n = z$ and the first statement follows. As for the other just use the counterexample given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(i)$ is true due to real number is closed under addition which is an axiom.

$(ii)$ is false.

Suppose such $z$ exists, then $z=0+0$ and $z=1+0$, hence $1=0$ which is a contradiction.